# How would be able to update a page division using jquery with content from another html file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've tried a few things although I can't seem to get the correct combination of code. Currently I am scripting a page in PHP, Jquery (which is new to me) and Javascript.

[php code]

```
// Define page number
if (!$pagenumber) {
    $pagenumber = 0;
}

$end = 6;
$newpage = 0;
echo '<h3>';

// Previous Page
if (($pagenumber >= 1) || ($pagenumber == $end)) {
    $newpage = $pagenumber - 1;
    echo '<a href="#" id="prev">Prev.</a>';
}

// Display initial page
$link = "../content/include/article/p".$newpage.".html";
include($link);
echo 'Page '.($pagenumber + 1).' of '.$end;

// Next page
if ($pagenumber < $end) {
    $newpage = $pagenumber + 1;
    echo '<a href="#" id="next">Next</a>';
}

echo '</h3>'."\n\n\n";
```

[/php code]

Anyway I tried to use some jQuery as opposed to some long winded javascript code. Essentially I need on the click event trigger a reload/refresh of the DIV content with a content of a different HTML file on the same server.

You can probably see that I am using PHP to increment/decrement the page value. The value from this should be carried across into the Javascript and passed as a variable in which the page content is reloaded from.

Does anybody know an easy or easier method to do this using either PHP or jQuery - preferably a dynamic method.

Much kudos for any help.

Aaron

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried jQuery's .load() method. You can load complete html page content or any div on the html page into div using load.

```
$( "#divID" ).load( "ajax/test.html" );
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For the moment I am using some code that takes the values from  a selection form although this wasn't what I was originally planning to do. More of a working compromise really.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
     $("form.submitForm").on("submit", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
  return false;
        });
     $(function() {
        $("#s").change(function() {
   if ($(this).val()) {
                $("#lh").load($(this).val());
                $("#m").submit(); }
   });
  });
</script>
This is the script for the form links although I would prefer another way.